# How to Update Datatable column value which is empty with default value

Tags: c#, datatable

I am having a `data table` as shown below:-

```
id  name    rollno  mobile

1   test1   101     1111
2   test2   102 
3   test3   103     1121
4   test4   104 
5   test5   105     3333
```

In `data table` the `mobile` column has some empty values.

If I do a bulk insert of this `data table` it gives an error.

I want to update the `mobile` column with 0(zero) if empty found.

How can i update it without looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this with LINQ expression:

```
tbl.Select().Where(x => x["mobile"] == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(x["mobile"].ToString())).ForEach(x => x["mobile"] = 0);
```

But remember, this is still a loop.